# Display all the contents of data item cognos

Tags: cognos

I am using Cognos 10 report studio. I have a data item DESCRIPTION which is a lengthy string. While I run the report last part of the DESCRIPTION is being truncated. I tried setting size and overflow it did not work for me.

Please help !!

Comment: There's an option to allow the wrapping of text columns. Have you tried that? Have you tried to force a greater width of the column? Could you include a partial screen shot of the effect?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But I have tried with word wrap, Size and Overflow etc but still  not able to get desired output. 
For Example if I want to display a text..
DESIRED TEXT-"From business intelligence to financial performance and strategy management to analytics applications, IBM Cognos software can provide what your organization needs to become top-performing and analytics-driven."                                            
 MY OUTPUT - "From business intelligence to financial performance and strategy management to analytics applications, IBM Co”
I want entire text to be displayed.

Comment: There definitely seems to be an issue with displaying text data items with lengths exceeding 1024 characters. We plan to raise a ticket with IBM for that. Your text is considerably shorter (334 characters). This type of length has not caused any trouble yet in our setup. I can only repeat my plea to provide screen shots of the output and maybe of the configuration settings. If you cannot upload them yet (due to lack of reputation) send the images to me and I will upload them.

Answer (score 0):

As a default, the 'White Space' setting on the column will determine its wrap behavior.  Manually setting it to 'Normal' should enforce a wrap.

The size and overflow settings can limit the width of a column, but a single long word will override that width limit (although the rest of your text will obey the width limit, leaving some strange looking columns.)  Leave size and overflow as the default (no limit) when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But I have tried with word wrap, Size and Overflow etc but still  not able to get desired output. 
For Example if I want to display a text..
DESIRED TEXT-"From business intelligence to financial performance and strategy management to analytics applications, IBM Cognos software can provide what your organization needs to become top-performing and analytics-driven."                                            
 MY OUTPUT - "From business intelligence to financial performance and strategy management to analytics applications, IBM Co”
I want entire text to be displayed.